# Pimcore - How to add custom button to object tree menu

Tags: extjs, pimcore

I would like to add a custom menu button to the object tree context menu of Pimcore 4.3.1, for example before the copy button:

[image: Object tree context menu]

I think the best solution would be a custom plugin:
https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Plugin_Developers_Guide/Plugin_Backend_UI.html

In the 'pimcoreReady' function of the plugin I am able to extend for example the main navigation and adding custom buttons... But I can't find anything about extending the object tree...

I already looked at */pimcore/static/js/pimcore/object/tree.js* where the original menu is created, but can'f find anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach using a custom plugin will work. The docs you mentioned, https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Plugin_Developers_Guide/Plugin_Backend_UI.html, shows a list of available javascript events.

The `prepare*TreeContextMenu` events are specifically ment to modify the context menu in the tree panels. You can execute a function for this event by simply adding it to you plugin class in the same way you did with the `pimcoreReady` event, like so:

```
pimcore.plugin.myplugin = Class.create(pimcore.plugin.admin, {
    prepareObjectTreeContextMenu: function (menu, treeClass, object) {

        // Modify ext menu
        menu.add({
            text: "My Button",
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_copy",
            handler: function () {
                console.log('Clicked menu button');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help and the example! I must have overlooked this... ;)